# Use of delete function - Herança de um QList

Tags: c++, qt, herança, qml

Ao compilar obtenho o seguinte erro, no *QList*. Estou utilizando o Qt 5.6.

**error: use of deleted function 'Vitamin::Vitamin(const Vitamin&)' current->v = new T(*reinterpret_cast(src->v));**

**error: use of deleted function 'Vitamin::Vitamin(const Vitamin&)' new (current) T(*reinterpret_cast(src));**

**error: use of deleted function 'Vitamin::Vitamin(const Vitamin&)' else if (QTypeInfo::isComplex) new (n) T(t);**

**error: use of deleted function 'Vitamin& Vitamin::operator=(const Vitamin&)' else *reinterpret_cast(n) = t;**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Classe Base

**Header**

```
#ifndef COMPONETNUTRITIONAL
#define COMPONETNUTRITIONAL

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>

class ComponentNutritional:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ComponentNutritional(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~ComponentNutritional();

    QString getName();
    float getValue();
    float getDairyValue();
    QString getMeasure();

protected:
    QString name;
    float value;
    float dairyvalue;
    QString measure;

};

#endif // COMPONETNUTRITIONAL
```

**Cpp**

```
#include "componetnutritional.h"

#include <typeinfo>

ComponentNutritional::ComponentNutritional(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{
    this->name = typeid(this).name();
    this->dairyvalue = 0;
    this->measure = "";
    this->value = 0;
}

ComponentNutritional::~ComponentNutritional()
{

}

QString ComponentNutritional::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}

float ComponentNutritional::getValue()
{
    return this->value;
}

float ComponentNutritional::getDairyValue()
{
    return this->dairyvalue;
}

QString ComponentNutritional::getMeasure()
{
    return this->measure;
}
```

### Classe que realiza a herança

**Header**

```
#ifndef VITAMIN_H
#define VITAMIN_H

#include <QObject>
#include "Library/Types/Base/componetnutritional.h"

class Vitamin : public ComponentNutritional
{
public:
    explicit Vitamin(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Vitamin();
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setName(QString value);
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setValue(float value);
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setDairyValue(float value);
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setMeasure(QString value);
};

class Vitamins: public QList<Vitamin>{
};
#endif // VITAMIN_H
```

**Cpp**

```
#include "vitamin.h"

Vitamin::Vitamin(QObject *parent): ComponentNutritional(parent)
{

}

Vitamin::~Vitamin()
{

}

Vitamin *Vitamin::setName(QString value)
{
    this->name = value;
    return this;
}

Vitamin *Vitamin::setValue(float value)
{
    this->value = value;
    return this;
}

Vitamin *Vitamin::setDairyValue(float value)
{
    this->dairyvalue = value;
    return this;
}

Vitamin *Vitamin::setMeasure(QString value)
{
    this->measure = value;
    return this;
}
```

### Solução

```
#ifndef VITAMIN_H
#define VITAMIN_H

#include <QObject>
#include "Library/Types/Base/componetnutritional.h"

class Vitamin : public ComponentNutritional
{
public:
    explicit Vitamin(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Vitamin();
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setName(QString value);
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setValue(float value);
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setDairyValue(float value);
    Q_INVOKABLE  Vitamin *setMeasure(QString value);
};

class Vitamins: public QList<Vitamin*>{ //Alterado para ponteiro
};
#endif // VITAMIN_H
```

Comment: Cara, você podia deixar essa pergunta mais enxuta e deixar só um exemplo mínimo, mas que demonstre o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#details):

> QList's value type must be an **assignable** data type.

Ou seja, para uma `QList<T>`, `T` tem que ser *assignable*, [isto é](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#assignable-data-type):

> To qualify, a type must provide a default constructor, **a copy constructor**, and an assignment operator.

Ou seja, o `T` tem que ser copiável ou prover um construtor de cópia. Classes derivadas de `QObject` explicitamente excluem o construtor de cópia, fazendo, no seu caso, com que `QList<Vitamin>` tente usar um construtor que não existe para o tipo (*deleted*). Já ponteiros, por serem valores primitivos, podem ser copiados; por isso, `QList<Vitamin *>` funciona.